# Notification can't go to current running activity

Tags: android, notifications

In my program, click the notification and it must go to current running activity. I have found many ways to do it but all fail.Please help me. 
Here is my alarm manager....

```
        private void startAlarm(long time,String stringtime){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    final int _id=(int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent myIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),timealarm.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("Start_time", stringtime);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),_id, myIntent, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, time, pendingIntent);
    //sendBroadcast(myIntent);
}
```

Here is broadcast.....

```
             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent paramIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    paramIntent.getStringExtra("Start_time");

    Intent myIntent=new Intent(context,service.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("Strar_time",paramIntent.getStringExtra("Start_time") );
    myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    context.startService(myIntent);
}
```

Here is service.....

```
         public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
     super.onStart(intent, startId);

     String startTime = intent.getStringExtra("Strar_time");

     NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
        int ww = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "reminder", when);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.vibrate = new long[]{100, 200, 100, 500};
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Goo.class);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), ww, notificationIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "It's about time", "Your time is "+startTime, contentIntent);
        nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);
        NOTIF_ID++;
        Log.i("NotiID",NOTIF_ID+"");

        if(NOTIF_ID == 2147483647){
            NOTIF_ID = 1;
            Log.i("pyyfwjflwej",NOTIF_ID+"");
        }
        stopSelf();
          }
```

Comment: is it opening new activity instead of current activity?

Comment: Yes, I want to show current activity but I always go new activity.